# Variable floating-point precision format string

Tags: go, format, format-string

I'm trying to print floating point numbers as percentages, and I'd like for the number of digits after the decimal place to vary as needed. Currently I have:

```
fmt.Printf("%.2f%%\n", 100*(value/total))
```

The problem is that if my percentage is, say, exactly 50, I will get the following output:

```
50.00%
```

While what I want is to get:

```
50%
```

Is there any way for the format string to indicate that a *maximum* of 2 digits of precision should be used, but only if needed?

Comment: 50% is 50% +- 0.5%; 50.00% is 50.00% +- 0.005%. They are not the same.

Comment: True, but for what I'm doing that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct solution with the `fmt` package.

But you can remove the dot and zeros at end with a regular expression:

```
r, _ := regexp.Compile(`\.?0*$`)
fmt.Printf("%s%%\n", r.ReplaceAllString(fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 100*(value/total)),""))
```

Bonus: the same regex works for any number of trailing zeros.

Side note: You'll display `50.0041` the same way than `50`, which might be a little misleading.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that inside `fmt` with e.g. another flag or what have you. You'll have to write out the logic yourself. You could do something like:

```
var final string
doubledecimal := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 100*value/total)
if doubledecimal[len(doubledecimal)-2:] == "00" {
    final = doubledecimal[:len(doubledecimal)-3]
} else {
    final = doubledecimal
}
fmt.Printf("%s%%\n, final)
```

You could similarly use `strings.Split` to split on the decimal point and work from there.

You could even adjust this to turn `50.10%` into `50.1%`.

```
doubledecimal := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", 100*value/total)
// Strip trailing zeroes
for doubledecimal[len(doubledecimal)-1] == 0 {
    doubledecimal = doubledecimal[:len(doubledecimal)-1]
}
// Strip the decimal point if it's trailing.
if doubledecimal[len(doubledecimal)-1] == "." {
    doubledecimal = doubledecimal[:len(doubledecimal)-1]
}
fmt.Printf("%s%%\n", doubledecimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to have an if statement controlling the print output, i.e. if the result is cleanly divisible by 1 (result%1 == 0) then print the result to no decimal places. Otherwise print to .2f as you've done above. Not sure if there is a shorter way of doing this, but I think this should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid, but it might come to that.

Comment: You can't use modulo on a `float64`

Comment: Ah ok I did not know this. It is not too hard to write something which is largely equivalent though and so the if else logic would work.